How to apply a function to specific rows of a matrix
I want to apply a function:
f[x_]:=x^2

I want to map it to certain values in a matrix, say
matrix={{1,2,3,4},{0,2,0,0},{0,0,3,0},{0,0,0,4}}

I want to map f to positions the entire $1^{st}$ and $3^{rd}$ row.
I have tried:
MapAt[f,matrix,{{1,3},All}]

But this does not work.
I am aware that I would be able to map f to the entire $1^{st}$ and $3^{rd}$ columns by using
MapAt[f,matrix,{All,{1,3}}]

So I am confused why it does not work the other way around for the rows?

Short answer:
MapAt[f, matrix, {{{1, 3}, All}}]

I haven't quite wrapped my head around it yet, but I think the initial {1,3} in
MapAt[f, matrix, {{1, 3}, All}]

sets an expectation somehow of the pattern of positions it expects. The position {1,3} is, by itself, a valid position spec and it specifies an element two levels deep. The All is sort of "dangling" and so somehow gets misinterpreted, maybe because there aren't enough levels in matrix, IDK.
But since we can pass a list of position specifications, we can just pass a single element list, as I showed above.

+1 The accepted answer must be yours :-)

According to MapAt documentation, you need to use the following to get what you are looking for:
MapAt[f, mat, {{1, All}, {3, All}}] // TeXForm


$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 f(1) & f(2) & f(3) & f(4) \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 f(0) & f(0) & f(3) & f(0) \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Also:
Thread@MapAt[f, Thread@mat, {All, {1, 3}}] // TeXForm


$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 f(1) & f(2) & f(3) & f(4) \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 f(0) & f(0) & f(3) & f(0) \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Or using SubsetMap:
SubsetMap[#^2 &, mat, {1, 3}] // TeXForm


$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 4 & 9 & 16 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 9 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$

Or using ReplacePart:
f[x_] := x^2

ReplacePart[mat, {{1, j_} :> f@mat[[1, j]], {3, j_} :> f@mat[[3, j]]}] //TeXForm


$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 4 & 9 & 16 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 9 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right)$


Query[All, Thread[{1, 3} -> g]]@Transpose@matrix // Transpose

(* {
     {g[1], g[2], g[3], g[4]}, 
     {0, 2, 0, 0}, 
     {g[0], g[0], g[3], g[0]}, 
     {0,0, 0, 4}
   } *)

For example
f[x_] := x^2

Query[All, Thread[{1, 3} -> f]]@Transpose@matrix // Transpose

(* {
     {1, 4, 9, 16}, 
     {0, 2, 0, 0}, 
     {0, 0, 9, 0}, 
     {0, 0, 0, 4}
   } *) 

Or, as a 'pure' function:
 Query[All, Thread[{1, 3} -> (#^2 &)]]@Transpose@matrix // Transpose


+1 I always like to see how you use Query :-)

@E.Chan-López Thanks!  It all comes from this post by Sjoerd Smit
